# elasticsearch NumberFormatException for strings containing numbers

Tags: logging, elasticsearch

I'm trying to set up a heka + elasticsearch + kibana stack for storing and searching in logs, and as such I have zero knowledge of elasticsearch, yet I've noticed that some log entries are dropped with an error message like this:

`[2016-03-02 09:37:17,440][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Madame MacEvil] [heka-2016.03.02][3] failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[heka-2016.03.02][message][AVM2eV_-J4Kw0FFvoFfq], source[{"host":"host1","error":"No delimiter found. Code 200","Timestamp":"2016-03-02T08:37:17","Severity":6}]}
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [error]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "No delimiter found. Code 200"];`

So apparently for some reason ES tries to parse an `error` string as a number and obviously fails.

How can this be fixed?